# Should my API gateway handle SOAP/Rest transformation

Tags: api, rest, soap, architecture

Here is the situation :

I have a partner service outside of my network. This service is a legacy one, using soap. My internal app needs to fetch data from this service but I don't wan't to work with soap/json. My first reflex is to expose this service on my internal API gateway to consume it but ...

My gateway can of course manage transformation Rest/soap but I want to avoid doing transformation  on the gateway as it is resources and time expensive.

I think of a facade component inside my network but this component will have to access public network directly and I feel this is not right.

What can I do ? Isn't it an anti pattern to get out of my network by another door than the gateway ?

Comment: How often do you need call the SOAP legacy system? How many different actions are you calling? How large is a usual payload?

Answer (score 0):

there are two type of gateway 
1- API gateway : which is for clients and users who need to use your APIs 
2- Service gateway : in SOA or MSA your services should not call external services directly (for security reasons and also for decoupling them from each other , maybe one of them working with REST and other one working with SOAP which is your case) rather you should use something which called integration services (integration frameworks) or ESBs (enterprise service bus). 
Your problem is you want to use your API gateway instead of service gateway.
Keep your API gateway for your clients but if your services need to call external services use an integration framework or a service bus.
One of the most main features of these tools is that they can convert protocols together for example they have convertors to convert SOAP to REST , it means you call it by REST but it will convert your call to SOAP and call the external service ( you just should config it to which protocol it should convert ).
And also there are many ready to use connectors in them which can connect your service bus to other applications and services like DBs, messaging platforms , linkedIn , ...... .
There are many ready to use ESBs like Apache camel , Mule ESB and .... .